# incrementing a non auto increment field during an insert based on a select in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm inserting records from one table into another table using a select statement. The table being inserted to has a new field that should be incremented by one in each update, but should not be an auto-increment field as the number needs to start again for each group of records per update. If the select statement being used selects 42 records, the new table would have a field that is incremented by 1 for each record starting with one. The next group should have this field at 1 again and then increment for each record that was selected. Is this possible to do? I'm having trouble finding the syntax to use as most of my searching just finds results about auto-increment keys.

```
INSERT into images (filename, imgpath, imagenumber)
SELECT filename, imgpath, 1+
FROM old_images
WHERE event_id = 20
```

This is a simple example of the tables, but I'm wondering if there is a way to increment what is being put into imagenumber field in the images table directly in mySql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at using [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Something along the lines of

```
SET @t1=0; 
INSERT into images (filename, imgpath, imagenumber) 
SELECT  filename, 
        imgpath, 
        @t1 := @t1+1 
FROM    old_images 
WHERE   event_id = 20
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need, but when I try to use the examples from the mysql as well as your example it always returns a null value for the variable. 

When I do the following in the query browser the column name contains the expression but the value is null. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: My problems were due to trying to do this in the mysql query editor. I tried the same sql from a coldfusion page and it worked correctly. I found an explanation that said the query browser makes a new connection for each row inserted which eliminates the variable each time.