# how to do an insert statement using a non auto increment ID?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, auto-increment

The same question has been asked for MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870999/incrementing-a-non-auto-increment-field-during-an-insert-based-on-a-select-in-mys), anyway that syntax doesn't work in SQL Server.

I paste the sample from that question (by simplifying it) here because it explains what I need very well.

```
DECLARE @t1 integer
SET @t1=0;
-- MyTable is a simple Table with 2 fields "MyID" and "MyValue"
insert into MyTable
SELECT  @t1 := @t1+1, --this "should" work in MySQL
  MyAnotherValue
FROM    AnotherTable
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in SQL Server (without using a cursor)?

Note: this is a to be run once query, it is a maintenance query, so race conditions and locks are not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, even if you run it more than once:

```
insert into MyTable(MyId, MyValue)
  select (select isnull(max(MyId), 0) from MyTable) + -- avoid duplicated keys, if you repeat this insert again
         row_number() over(order by MyAnotherValue),
         MyAnotherValue
    from AnotherTable
```

The `isnull()` function covers the case when `MyTable` is empty

Comment: Thanks, also Barry answer is appropriate (and i gave +1 there too) but your answer is perfect because it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
Insert Into dbo.AnotherTable (Col1, Col2)
Select Row_Number() Over(Order By SomeColumn),
       SomeColumn

From dbo.YourTable
```